# stringByAppendingString in for-loop

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, nsstring

I want to make my string: @"test" to @"----"

In console i get: "object returned empty description"

I try to make for every character in foo a "-" in foo2, so that i get: "----" but it is not working. Ive looked and find out to first init my string but i do tho with: @"" or am i wrong? but it also does not woe with [NSString new].

where is the bug ?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{ 
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *foo = @"test";
    NSString *foo2 = @"";

    for(int i=0; i < foo.count; i++)
    {
        [foo2 stringByAppendingString:@"-"];
    }

    NSLog(foo2);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
for(int i=0; i < foo.count; i++)
{
    [foo2 stringByAppendingString:@"-"];
}
```

to

```
for(int i=0; i < foo.length; i++)
{
    foo2 = [foo2 stringByAppendingString:@"-"];
}
```

Comment: I have just checked and everything works! if foo == @"test", then foo2 == @"----". Should it work this way?

Comment: ohh... you are right :)  i've overlooked 'the foo2 ='  but really it works great! THNAK YOU!!

Answer (score 1):

Always use `NSLog(@"%@", object)` Otherwise you will get compiler error ->  "Potentially Insecure"

For string manipulation consider NSMutableString.

The same code can be written with NSMutableString as,

```
NSMutableString *foo2 = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@""];
for(int i=0; i < [foo length] ; i++){
    [foo2 appendString:@"-"];
 } 
NSLog(@"%@", foo2);
```